# iphone provisioning profile

Tags: iphone

I have been through the device provisioning several times, and I still don't understand it.

I have one phone and one ipad provisioned to work, but I can't get another phone to work.

All the devices are listed in the apple provisioning profile-devices and show the provisioning profile that I am using.

On both phones, in XCode 4, under organizer-devices, I deleted the existing provisioning profiles on each device. Then I downloaded the current provisioning profile from the apple provisioning portal and dropped it onto the XCode organizer-devices for each device.

I can still load my application on the two devices that were working originally. But the third device is a no-go.

The ipad runs ios version 4.3
The working phone runs ios 4.01 (jailbroken)
The non-working phone runs ios version 3.1.3 (jailbroken)

The non-working phone does not show up in the schema device list in Xcode 4.

I'm obviously not sure what it is that I missed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does "is a no-go" mean? Are you able to load the application but not run it? What's wrong?

Comment: What's to understand?  Apple is making your life as a developer needlessly difficult and complicated.  Because our misery sustains them.

Comment: Sorry. By no-go, I mean xcode is not even recognizing the device. when I plug either of the other devices in, the schema (eventually) shows the name of the device. When I plug the one phone in, it is not recognized within the schema (It just says "iOS Device"). The phone itself works fine and is recognized by the xcode organizer and by iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the device ID of all devices you use in the provisioning profile. The minimum OS version of the project must be <= your device OS version. If the device is an arm6 based device you might have accidentially disabled dual builing for arm6/arm7.

I think you probably set the deployment target too high and/or statically linked a framework that required >= iOS 4

PS: it is also very likely that Jailbreaking is responsible for the device not being recognized by the organizer. Have a look at the console log both on Xcode and on the device. Jailbreaking might be causing a crash in your baseband when Xcode tries to probe it.

Comment: I remember seeing something for setting the minimum OS version, but I can't remember where I found it in XCode 4. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think I answered my own question with this link: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html. I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: The answer is to set the minimum OS version in the build setting.